# lua-resty-openidc: Entry thread aborted: runtime error: attempt to call field 'start' (a nil value)

Tags: nginx, lua, nginx-ingress, lua-resty-openidc

###### Environment

- lua-resty-openidc      : v1.7.5
- OpenID Connect provider: Keycloak

###### This is what I'm doing

For the info, I'm using it on our `ingress-nginx-controller`, with the entire content copied from `/usr/local/openresty/lualib/resty` to `/etc/nginx/lua/`. When the UI endpoint (i.e. https://ingress.myproject.local/myui) is called, it supposed to redirect the the connection to Keycloak. I have a client called `myui` under the *master* realm in Keycloak.

###### This my current code

```
location ~* "^/myui(/|$)(.*)" {
  .....
  .....
  access_by_lua_block {
      local opts = {
          redirect_uri = "/redirect_uri",
          accept_none_alg = true,
          discovery = "http://keycloak.myproject.local:8080/auth/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration",
          client_id = "myui",
          client_secret = "ABCDEFgHIJKLMnOPQRSTuVWXYZ",
          redirect_uri_scheme = "https",
          logout_path = "/logout",
          redirect_after_logout_uri = "http://keycloak.myproject.local:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=https://ingress.myproject.local/myui/",
          redirect_after_logout_with_id_token_hint = false,
          session_contents = {id_token=true}
      }
      -- call introspect for OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token validation
      local res, err = require("resty.openidc").authenticate(opts)
           if err then
             ngx.status = 403
             ngx.say(err)
             ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
           end
      }
     
      expires       0;
      add_header    Cache-Control private;
  }
}
```

###### This is what I get

Upon running, I get `500 Internal Server Error` on the browser, with the error msg:

```
[error] 549#549: *123249 lua entry thread aborted:  run time error: /etc/nginx/lua/resty/openidc.lua:1459: attempt to call field 'start' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
coroutin 0:
     /etc/nginx/lua/resty/openidc.lua: in function 'authenticate' 
     access_by_lua(nginx.conf:1075): 16: in main chunk, client xx.xx.xx.xx , server:  ingress.myproject.local, request: "GET /myui HTTP/2.0", host: "ingress.myproject.local"
```

I don't see anything significant in the log related to that. Any idea why I'm getting this or what am I doing wrong?

-S

Comment: Where did /etc/nginx/lua/resty/openidc.lua come from? What's on and around line 1459 of it?

Comment: it's from this repo:
https://github.com/zmartzone/lua-resty-openidc/blob/master/lib/resty/openidc.lua

Comment: Rest of the *.lua are copied from openresty image: https://hub.docker.com/r/openresty/openresty

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for https://github.com/zmartzone/lua-resty-openidc says:

> You will need
> to install two extra pure-Lua dependencies that implement session management and HTTP client functions:
>
> - [`lua-resty-http`](https://github.com/pintsized/lua-resty-http)
> - [`lua-resty-session`](https://github.com/bungle/lua-resty-session)

It would appear that you didn't install lua-resty-session. The error you're getting is because r_session is nil, which was defined as `local r_session = require("resty.session")`.

Comment: I have `/etc/nginx/lua/resty/session.lua` present - is it not enough?

Comment: @MacUsers Is /etc/nginx/lua in your package.path? Did you put the session directory there too?

Comment: okay, I see the `session` directory and `http` are actually missing. I'm putting that in now and will feed back shortly.

Comment: hi there! sorry for the late reply. Now I have all `session` directory and all of the `http` luas as well but still failing with exactly the same error. The _PATH_ wise it should be okay, otherwise it wouldn't find `openidc.lua` in the first place, right?

Comment: I'm running out of ideas: cannot figure out at all what's going wrong. Any other thoughts from anyone pls?

Comment: Any Lua/Nginx  expert out here to help pls? I tried whatever I could, making sure `session`, `http` are present with all the necessary directories etc. but still no joy. I have to look for some alternative if I don't make any progress today. Any help will be really appreciated.